# Importing .zip file

Tags: import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Importing Zip files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2871/importing-zip-files)

I have a piece of code which imports a txt file and turns it automatically into a table form. I use the following:

```
Import["filename.txt","Table"];
```

Now I have a txt file in a zipped folder which I want to Import. After importing I also want to convert it into a Table. But:

```
Import["filename.zip","filename2.txt","Table"];
```

does not work because it contains three arguments. How can I solve this?

Regards,
RA

Comment: Try `Import["filename.zip",{"filename2.txt","Table"}]`