# Import from ZIP as specific format

Tags: import

I have a [ZIP](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/ZIP.html) archive that does not have the `.zip` file extension. How can I import a file from this archive using [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) and specifying a particular [import format or element](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html)?

---

Test case:

```
SetDirectory@CreateDirectory[]
x = 1;
Export["x.m", HoldComplete[x], "HeldExpressions"]
CreateArchive["x.m"]
RenameFile["x.m.zip", "a.foo"]
```

Now I can

```
Import["a.foo", {"ZIP", "x.m"}]
(* 1 *)
```

But I want to import `x.m` as [`"HeldExpressions"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Package.html).  How can I do this?  I cannot figure out the syntax.

---

Doing this is useful because lots of file formats are based on zip, e.g. Java JAR files, [Microsoft Office files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions), `.paclet` files, etc.  Suppose I want to import an XML from a `.docx` or I want to import a `PacletInfo.m` as `"HeldExpressions"`.

I know I can [`ExtractArchive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExtractArchive.html) first, import, and delete the extracted file. This question is about whether this is achievable with a single `Import` call.

Comment: let me guess what you are just trying :-). Have you tried `Import["a.foo", {"ZIP", "x.m", "HeldExpressions"}]`, that seems to work for me... It even is kind of documented in the details section of `Import` (in the part "assume also compression formats...")

Comment: @AlbertRetey Please post an answer ... I really couldn't find it

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2871/121

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
 Import["a.foo", {"ZIP", "x.m", "HeldExpressions"}]
```

the documentation is not really clear about it, but the explanation about compressed formats in the Details section of the `Import` documentation page can be read as if this should work.